# SublimeLinter could not determine shell PATH

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

Here's the error message I get each time I start Sublime Text:

> SublimeLinter could not determine your shell PATH. It is unlikely that
>   any linters will work.
>
> Please see the troubleshooting guide for info on how to debug PATH
>   problems.

I'm running Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: What were you doing when you got the error message? What linter were you trying to use? What operating system are you using? Did you read the troubleshooting guide, and if so what, if any actions did you take? Please [edit] your question to provide additional details, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks for pointing that out. I hope I have provided sufficient info.

I couldn't get any help in Sublime Text's troubleshooting guide, or anywhere else on the Web, including StackOverflow.

Comment: +1 also having this problem

Comment: I just added /usr/bin/zsh to the paths in the settings file and it seems to be solved for now, although I do not understand why this package can not find this path by itself.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and after I add an empty ~/.bash_profile, it was resolved.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions above worked for me, and here is what I did:

1. Press `command + shift + p` or `ctrl + shift +p` and enter "sublimelinter settings" and select `SublimeLinter Settings - User`
2. Scroll down until you see the `paths` section, here is mine:

```
    "paths": {
         "linux": [],
         "osx": 
               "/Users/cheng/.nvm/versions/node/v5.6.0/bin/",
               "/usr/local/bin/",
               "/bin/"
         ],
         "windows": []
     },
```

I have many different versions of `node` and `python` installed on my machine, so I just specify which version of those I want to use. Also, the last `/bin/` is used when sublimelinter complains about not being able to find the shell path.

Answer (score 2):

I found that upgrading SublimeLinter to version 3.0.35 fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had to set the path in my Sublime Linter User preferences, I referred to the help provided below.

http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#debugging-path-problems